# Is it possible to change API level of mobile and test our app by using android app?

Tags: android

I want to make an app in which we can change API level of mobile temporarily and test our apps.So,
Is it possible to change API level of mobile and test our app by using android app?
If it is possible then how we can do this in android applications by using Java.

Comment: no, you can't, because API level depends upon OS installed

Comment: No, it's not. The API level cannot change without a system update. What I would suggest is to find either cheap devices for each API or start using different emulators for each API level.

Comment: thanks for you suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No deployed version of OS of any sort contains its previous releases (don't confuse this with OS backward compatibility). The simplest way to test on various versions of given platform is to use emulator(s).

For Android see either [stock one](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) or 3rd party ones like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or [Blue Stacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via emulator.
I don't think that it's possible to do with mobile.